# Feasibility of creating a Timeline control using Grid

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

I want to create a timeline WPF control (as in this (http://www.taterboy.com/blog/images/MotionEditor/classic_vs_custom.png) kind of timeline - for animation editing).

I prototyped a simple Winforms control like this by drawing everything manually in a PaintEvent handler, and though it worked and was probably the most efficient way it wasn't flexible or attractive.

I am making a fully featured control using WPF, and wondered about the possibility of using a Grid control as the timeline - each discrete time position represented by a column (shaded when a keyframe is present) and tracks by the rows.

I don't though, know anything about this control, and this is the first time ive used WPF so I was wondering if anyone could comment on this idea?

Specifically, from a performance standpoint, is the grid designed to be used this way or is it more for structuring a gui at design time? Will I incur a serious performance penalty trying to modify its configuration dynamically, with a large number of elements? (~2000-3000 would be a likely worst case)

From a coding standpoint, how easy is it to modify the grid? And to do things like shading the cells for example? Is it a simple matter of `Grid.NumberOfColumns = x` or must every element be a unique object?

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a `Grid` is certainly an option and working with the `Grid` within XAML and code behind is fairly trivial.

```
    <Grid Name="MyGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>

    MyGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() 
              { Width = new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Star) });
```

You could then use a `Rectangle` to take care of your shading.

```
<Rectangle Grid.Column="0"></Rectangle>
```

The problem will come down to performance however you *may* be able to get by depending on a variety of factors. If the performance is a hinderance a different approach may be to use a [VirtualizingStackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx) as the underlying layout container within an [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) as it will address [UI virtualization](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=344). [Data virtualization](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=344) could also become an issue and should be addressed after UI vritualization via the `VirtualizingStackPanel`. The `ItemsControl` will allow you to provide a [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx) for items and should be a better approach in the long run to using the `Grid` based on your initial statement with regard to the size.

Expression Blend was built using WPF and has extensive support for animation; including an interactive and robust timeline, so it can be done. Understanding WPF is the key otherwise you will end up refactoring your initial approach as your understanding grows. Try, if you can, to get a decent foundation on how WPF differs from WinForms (it is drastic) as it will make your life easier down the road.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; i've spent a while reading more on WPF and and the more I do the more I understand how different it is from Winforms, but also the more impressed I am with it!
I am thinking now i'll use the virtualizingStackPanel to create essentially a 'static table' of potential keyframes and then the user can scale and move this under a 'viewer' area to work with just those they want, if I am understanding this right.
To use the control like this each keyframe or nonkeyframe section would have to be represented by rectangle objects correct? Am I able to reuse these when filling?

Comment: (Just in case that last sentance wasn't clear (character limit), I mean have one object to represent a 'keyframe' and another to represent 'nothing', then I would fill my horizontal panel with say 10 'nothing rectangles' and one 'keyframe rectangle' to indicate a keyframe at that point in time)
Thanks!

Comment: @sebf That could work...the Rectangle is a visual; not a container however it can still be reused and stored within a container. If you want the keyframe to contain content then you will need to wrap it with perhaps a Border/Grid. Think Grid -> Rectangle/TextBlock where Rectangle/TextBlock are at the same level in the tree and the Rectangle provides the visual whereas the TextBlock provides the content.

Comment: @Aaron Thank you, I think I understand - Grid/Border is the object that StackPanel lists and rectangle is the member that is 'drawn'. I can see seperate objects for each keyframe is best as this will do doubt make it easier when it comes to selection and moving them around, even if they still look the same. Ideally I would bind my keyframe list to the StackPanel and have it create and space the 'keyframe controls/objects', but all the examples I have seen are much more literal - listing strings or buttons - the StackPanel would need to know how to visualize the _lack_ of frames also.

Comment: @sebf If you had a list of objects you could obviously bind the stack panel to this list. If you had the list set in a horizontal manner versus a vertical then you would simply provide varying DataTemplates for the item types. You can then make use of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx which will allow you to specify the given DataTemplate for the given item; where each can have its own margins/spacing/behavior, etc...

Comment: @Aaron, I see, so I could use DataTemplateSelector and DataTemplates to pack my StackPanel's list with one or more 'null keyframe' objects of varying sizes depending on the time offset of the keyframes when they are added (bound). Looks like I have alot of reading to do! But a proper plan for this control now. Thanks for your help!